# Raspberry Pi randomly loses Wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, power-management

I have an issue with Raspberries that I run on my network. After a random amount of time, the Raspberries lose connection to the Wifi (not all at the same time, totally independant from each other). They recover after a certain time (usually 5-30 minutes) by themselves but cannot be accessed by SSH or Web Interface in that period. I checked that Power Management is turned off, nevertheless the problem persists.

[image: iwconfig]

I'm using a Raspbian Lite image on a Raspberry Pi 4. Is there anything I can do to investigate this further?

Comment: you spelled the [E]SSID wrong, it should 8_Hz_WAN_IP :)

Comment: wifi is being abuse by all and sundry. It's a wonder you can get any signal with others playing videos and what else over it on multiple ssid's, over all available channels. Where I am, the entire spectrum operates at 100% capacity during the day.

Comment: did you explicitly turn off wifi power save? I had the same problem, until I started running `/sbin/iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`.

Comment: Yes, power_save is turned off. I even run a script every 2 minutes that checks for wifi connectivity (pings the router) and restarts the wifi adapter if the connection is down. But even that doesnt seem to help

Answer (score 0):

I myself had this problem and there is next to nothing that you can do about it if you had the same problem that I did.

Fortunately for me, I had a EE with snazzy tools in the room to help me troubleshoot.

Both the HDMI connections and wifi on the board were poorly shielded (in both RasPi3, and 4) and as long as I had an HDMI connection plugged in, the wifi was shite.

We tried higher end cables and this made no difference.  Only using Ethernet solved it for me where I could both use the display and have a stable connection.

To test if this is what is happening to you, remove the HDMI plug (if you are using one) and remote into the box.  Did the problem go away with the removal of HDMI?

I am not saying that this is your problem, I am saying that this was ***my*** problem and possibly yours too.

Comment: Good idea to think about. I dont have any HDMI devices attached, though

Comment: So no cable plugged in? .. then I have nothing :(  Sorry.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late.
I dont have an HDMI connected. I'm operating the Pi remotely.
Thanks for sharing the thought, tho!